# What is ethically wrong in xenotransplantation?(transplanting animal's organ to a man)

Tags: ethics

> **The ethical before the technical**

Research in recent years has concentrated mainly on the effectiveness of xenotransplantation and other fundamental questions must be studied before moving on to clinical trials: physiology and safety, but also ethics and the regulatory aspects of xenotransplantations.’ Even if the problem of immune rejection is resolved there is nothing to indicate that pig organs will be able to replace human organs. The blood cholesterol level of pigs is lower than that of man, for example. In the case of a pig heart transplant, the high cholesterol levels in man could block the arteries. Also, organs such as the liver, kidneys, lungs and pancreas are all subject to hormonal control and it is not known whether animal organs can be regulated by human hormones. Even if these physiological problems could be fully resolved, an in-depth ethical reflection would be needed before xenotransplantation could become current practice. What would be the criteria, for example, in deciding whether a transplant patient will receive a human organ or a pig organ? As Emanuele Cozzi concludes, ‘until these questions are resolved in a satisfactory manner, I believe, and I am not alone, that it is not yet the time to begin clinical trials.

> [W]hat is ethically wrong here? What would be the criteria, for example, in deciding whether a transplant patient will receive a human organ or a pig organ? is this ethical problem? i think it is not ethically wrong because it's person's choice and xenotransplantation has good side too for example man can choose animal's organ because they may not want to be saved by the sacrifice of another person and they may feel guilty if they take man's organ.imagine you need a heart and would you take animals organ or man's? i think choosing is not ethically wrong.

Comment: what are you saying man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be two ethical concerns here; the welfare of the human patient and the welfare of the animal.

Concerns for the welfare of the patient are the same as in all medicine, they hinge around the case-by-case balance between the likely personal benefit against the risks of harmful side effects. The medical profession work hard to keep informed when making that kind of decision.

Concerns for the welfare of the animal will, as with pets, farming and lab experiments generally, depend principally on the quality of life of the animal, which will probably have to come from a pool of specially-raised medical stock. Besides the indirectly-related concerns for routine animal husbandry, there may potentially be concerns about specially-prepared animals being raised with an artificial handicap of some kind (recall the mouse with a human ear on its back). This has the potential to prove a contentious area; we need only remember how the introduction of GM crops was badly handled and caused a major ethical backlash.

Oh, there's another potential area of concern - assertion of intellectual property rights. Some companies have actually tried to patent genes and other treatments which become an integral part of the patient's physiology, just as they did with GM plants. Bad enough being sued as a neighbouring farmer when GM pollen blows across and breeds itself into your crops, imagine being sued because you went to a different doctor who did not have a commercial license to tamper with your patented treatment! Such legal actions seem a tad unethical to me.

Vegetarians, animal rights activists and religious adherents with beliefs about bodily pollution might well choose to decline treatment, but they could not force others to.

Comment: Intriguing to see several downvotes without comment. Do I sense personal agendas?